# Is there a mistake in pytorch tutorial?

Tags: python, pytorch

The official pytorch tutorial (https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/autograd_tutorial.html#gradients) indicates that `out.backward()` and `out.backward(torch.tensor(1))` are equivalent. But this does not seem to be the case.

```
import torch

x = torch.ones(2, 2, requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = y * y * 3
out = z.mean()

# option 1    
out.backward()

# option 2. Replace! do not leave one after the other
# out.backward(torch.tensor(1))

print(x.grad)
```

Using option 2 (commented out) results in an error.

**Note**: do not leave two backward calls. Replace option 1 with 2.

Is the tutorial out of date? What is the purpose of the argument?

*Update*
If I use `out.backward(torch.tensor(1))` as the tutorial says, I get:

```
E       RuntimeError: invalid gradient at index 0 - expected type torch.FloatTensor but got torch.LongTensor

../../../anaconda3/envs/phd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:90: RuntimeError
```

I tried also using `out.backward(torch.Tensor(1))` and I get instead:

```
E       RuntimeError: invalid gradient at index 0 - expected shape [] but got [1]

../../../anaconda3/envs/phd/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:90: RuntimeError
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `dtype=torch.float`:

```py
import torch

x = torch.ones(2, 2, requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = y * y * 3
out = z.mean()

# option 1    
out.backward()
print(x.grad)


x = torch.ones(2, 2, requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = y * y * 3
out = z.mean()



#option 2. Replace! do not leave one after the other
out.backward(torch.tensor(1, dtype=torch.float))

print(x.grad)
```

**Output:**

```
tensor([[ 4.5000,  4.5000],
        [ 4.5000,  4.5000]])
tensor([[ 4.5000,  4.5000],
        [ 4.5000,  4.5000]])
```